# Django 1.9.4 + Djangae + rest_framework (warning deprecate)

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm using Django 1.9.4 + Djangae + rest_framework for my project.

Everthing is working well but I got a warning when I launch my server by "python manage.py runserver"

Stacktrace :

> lib/django/core/management/base.py:265: RemovedInDjango110Warning: > OptionParser usage for Django management commands is deprecated, use > > ArgumentParser instead
>     RemovedInDjango110Warning)
>
> WARNING  2016-06-20 18:47:22,439 base.py:265] > lib/django/core/management/base.py:265: RemovedInDjango110Warning: > OptionParser usage for Django management commands is deprecated, use > ArgumentParser instead
>     RemovedInDjango110Warning)

Someone know how to fix that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely ignore the warning.

As it points out, OptionParser was removed in Django 1.10. Djangae just updated itself to remove its usage (see https://github.com/potatolondon/djangae/issues/749). The Djangae fix hasn't yet been deployed to `pip` (as of 9/22/16), but unless you're using Django 1.10+, it doesn't matter.